# Groovy code is not highlighted

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, groovy, eclipse-plugin, highlighting

I downloaded the Eclipse directly from eclipse downloads page - the [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=linux) and unzipped it

however, when I open .groovy file, its not highlighted. I tried to download and run [Groovy plugin](http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e3.7/) from [this page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin)

During installing, the eclipse tells me, that groovy is already installed:

```
 Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
 Software being installed: Groovy-Eclipse M2E integration 2.7.1.xx-20120921-2000-e37RELEASE (org.codehaus.groovy.m2eclipse.feature.group 2.7.1.xx-20120921-2000-e37RELEASE)
 Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.5.1.20121004-1506 (epp.package.jee 1.5.1.20121004-1506)
 Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
 Object Teams Development Tooling Core 3.8.1.v_OTDT_r210_201206090452 (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.8.1.v_OTDT_r210_201206090452)
 Java Development Tools Core 3.8.1.v20120531-0637 (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.8.1.v20120531-0637)
Object Teams Development Tooling Core 3.8.2.v_OTDT_r211_201209011847 (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.8.2.v_OTDT_r211_201209011847)
Java Development Tools Core 3.8.2.v20120814-155456 (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.8.2.v20120814-155456)
Java Development Tools Core 3.7.3.xx-20120921-2000-e37RELEASE (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.7.3.xx-20120921-2000-e37RELEASE)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.5.1.20121004-1506 (epp.package.jee 1.5.1.20121004-1506)
To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.5.1.20121004-1506]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Groovy-Eclipse Feature 2.7.1.xx-20120921-2000-e37RELEASE (org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.feature.feature.group 2.7.1.xx-20120921-2000-e37RELEASE)
To: org.codehaus.groovy.jdt.patch.feature.group [2.7.1.xx-20120921-2000-e37RELEASE]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Groovy-Eclipse Feature 2.7.1.xx-20120921-2000-e37RELEASE (org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.feature.feature.group 2.7.1.xx-20120921-2000-e37RELEASE)
To: org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 0.0.0
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Groovy-Eclipse M2E integration 2.7.1.xx-20120921-2000-e37RELEASE (org.codehaus.groovy.m2eclipse.feature.group 2.7.1.xx-20120921-2000-e37RELEASE)
To: org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.5.1.20121004-1506 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.5.1.20121004-1506)
To: org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 0.0.0
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: JDI Debug UI 3.6.100.v20120530-1425 (org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 3.6.100.v20120530-1425)
To: bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core [3.8.0,4.0.0)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From Patch: org.codehaus.groovy.jdt.patch.feature.group 2.7.1.xx-20120921-2000-e37RELEASE Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.8.0.v20120525-1249-8-8nFqlFNOfwKDRGz-pXLdGxEM83 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.8.0.v20120525-1249-8-8nFqlFNOfwKDRGz-pXLdGxEM83)
To: org.eclipse.jdt.core [3.7.3.xx-20120921-2000-e37RELEASE]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From Patch: org.codehaus.groovy.jdt.patch.feature.group 2.7.1.xx-20120921-2000-e37RELEASE Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.8.1.v20120814-104540-8-8nFqpFNOfwKDRVz-tXOcL5d_83 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.8.1.v20120814-104540-8-8nFqpFNOfwKDRVz-tXOcL5d_83)
To: org.eclipse.jdt.core [3.7.3.xx-20120921-2000-e37RELEASE]
```

But the code is still not highlighted... Can you tell me what next steps should I try to get the code highlighted?

Comment: You installed the zip downloaded the plugin? I think that if you install the plugin through eclipse it will show the dependency errors and suggest you to download them.

Comment: I did put the URL in install new SW. Anyway, I did solve it already. Should I delete my own question or post solution?

Comment: I never made a question, is there a "close" option?

Comment: close votes are for the option that the question should not be there. I will keep it open, may it help also someone else having same issue...

Answer (score 1):

[The most likely cause for this is that you are editing your groovy file in a Java editor.](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin+FAQ#EclipsePluginFAQ-Q.Whyisgroovy-awaresyntaxhighlightingnotworking?)

Answer (score 0):

Reopening the groovy file fixed it for me.